# Why does invoking a module with -m option set sys.path[0] to empty string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script `foo.py` in my current directory `C:\test`.

Here is the code.

```
import sys
print('sys.path:', sys.path)
print('sys.argv:', sys.argv)
```

When I execute it as a script, I see this output.

```
C:\test>python foo.py
sys.path: ['C:\\test', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
sys.argv: ['foo.py']
```

But when I execute it as a module, I see this output.

```
C:\test>python -m foo
sys.path: ['', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
sys.argv: ['C:\\test\\foo.py']
```

Why does `sys.path[0]` become empty string when I execute my program as a module?

The documentation at http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.path mentions this:

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list,
>   path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to
>   invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not
>   available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the
>   script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string,
>   which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first.

So if the script directory is not available, only then it is supposed to set `sys.path[0]` to `''`. But in my case, even while executing `python -m foo`, the script directory `foo` is clearly available. So it should not set `sys.path[0]` to `''` as per the documentation. Instead, it should set it to `'C:\\test'`.

Is it a bug in the documentation or a bug in the Python interpreter or a bug in my understanding?

Comment: Where do you see the empty string? In both cases `sys.path` has a *non empty* first element. The difference is whether or not it contains the full or relative path.

Comment: @Bakuriu Where do you see a non empty first element? You don't see an empty string in this output: `sys.path: ['', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']`?

Comment: Touchè. When reading the output I misread `sys.argv` for `sys.path`.

Answer (score 7):

Look at what `man python` says about `-m`:

> `-m module-name`
>
> > Searches `sys.path` for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as a script.

If you think about it, it makes no sense to add the directory containing the .py file to be run into `sys.path`, as it already has to be there to be found in the first place. So, IMO, the behavior is correct.

But the documentation says that if it is run as a script, the directory containing it should be prepended to `sys.path`. I would say that it is an error in the documentation, it should say:

> [...] (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input **or if the script is run using the `-m` option**) [...]

Comment: What does it mean man and how do I install it to the start menu?

Comment: @Cuadue: `man` is the standard Unix command to read the manual pages. You just go to a terminal and run the command `man <command>`. If you don't know it, probably you are running a non Unix-like system, such as Windows, where you don't have an easy alternative. For Python at least you have the integrated help files. For everything else... you have the Internet! To get a feel of what it is like, visit the [Linux man pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/).

Comment: if you think the docs should be improved; you could [submit documentation patch](http://docs.python.org/devguide/docquality.html)